# Serialization Method error

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

Hello I have model Brand and model BrandEditor which is used as mask to collect all personal brands of company. I want to add Brand to BrandEditor of user, which is creating the brand instance and If there is no BrandEditor - first create it. Have a code:

```
class BrandAddSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    editor = serializers.SerializerMethodField('create_editor')

    class Meta:
        model = Brand
        fields = ('id', 'editor', 'name', 'image', 'description')

    def create_editor(self):
        if BrandEditor.objects.filter(owner__user=CurrentUserDefault).exists():
            editor = BrandEditor.objects.filter(owner__user=CurrentUserDefault)
            return editor
        else:
            company = Company.objects.filter(user=CurrentUserDefault)
            BrandEditor.objects.create(owner=company)
            editor = BrandEditor.objects.filter(owner__user=CurrentUserDefault)
            return editor
```

I catch `create_editor() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`, what am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method binded to `SerializerMethodField` takes object as second argument. So you need to define it like this:

```
def create_editor(self, obj):
```

**UPD**

Also `CurrentUserDefault` is class using to provide default value to serializer field. To get current user inside method, you can use this instead ([related part](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context) of the docs):

```
user = self.context['request'].user
company = Company.objects.filter(user=user)
```

Comment: looks like progress, but now i get this - int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'type', or I'm mistaken with obj

Comment: @D.Make check updated answer. You need to call `CurrentUserDefault()` to get user object.

Comment: Thanks, but it looks soo bad, now i catch TypeError - int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'CurrentUserDefault'.

Comment: @D.Make hm.. looks like `CurrentUserDefault` doesn't work this way. Try to get user from context. Check another update.

Comment: looks like it works. I get another mistake - Cannot assign "<QuerySet [<Company: 123123123>]>": "BrandEditor.owner" must be a "Company" instance, but I hope to solve it myself, thanks!